# Pull off and hammer on alternatives?

Tags: electric-guitar, fingering, punk

I’m trying to learn Hate Every Beautiful Day by Sugarcult, and on the B string, with the tab it says 4p2h4. How would I do that, and is there an easier alternative? That’s the only thing stopping me from learning the intro. Also, I’m using the free version of Ultimate Guitar for this tab.

Edit: This is the first song I ever really wanted to learn, and I tried picking the notes, but the song goes too fast for me to pick them. I just recently started trying to learn it and I think what makes it hard for me is that it’s not an outside string, like either of the e strings. If you need the tab, I’ll just put the link to the tab I’m using.
https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/sugarcult/hate-every-beautiful-day-tabs-42036

```
[Intro]
  Guitar 1
e|----4-2----4-2----4-2------------|
B|--0------0------0------0--4p2h4--|
G|---------------------------------|
D|---------------------------------|
A|---------------------------------|
E|---------------------------------|
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to explain why you find pull-off and hammer-on to be difficult?  (I find them easier than picking each note.)

Comment: Most people wouldn't find the alternative to pull offs and hammer ons easier. The only alternative is to pick each note. If that's easier for you, that's the answer. If it's not easier for you, then you'll have to keep practicing until you can either play it with the hammer ons and pull offs, or until you can play it by picking each note.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the same sound there is no alternative. Plucking every note or using bends will give you a different sound that what is on the recording.

That being said, after listening to the intro on the recording and looking at the TAB I would say that the hammer-on back to 4 is non-existent, that note sounds like it is plucked. Doing the 4p2 then plucking 4 instead of hammering it will make this slightly easier to play, and it sounds like what the guitarist is doing anyway.

The trick to a good pull off is to have a finger  holding the lower fretted note firmly before playing the upper note. You also want to slightly pull down on the string then release it with the upper finger. You are essentially plucking the string with the finger you pull off with. In this case using fingers 3-1 make sense. Make sure your first finger is holding down fret 2 firmly before plucking fret 4 and then pulling off.

FYI for future reference the trick to a good hammer-on is to slap the finger onto the fret quickly and percussively as if you were hitting a drum. You also want to make sure you are coming straight down on the string, not at an angle from above or below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sceptical that any notes are pulled off or hammered on, but it's difficult to tell. Have you tried picking down and up with the plectrum? That would give a fair representation, and speed up your playing.

It's not *that* fast, though, and if you really want to follow what the tab says (remember, it's one person's translation of what really happens), Keep the index finger on fret 2, play the note on the 4th fret, with middle or ring finger, then pull slightly sideways with that back down to the still held on index. Then hammer on with the middle or ring finger again, 4th fret.

It's easier to practise this on the top string initially, as there's more room for the pull-off, but eventually, you'll get to pull off sideways within 3 or 4 mm, while pressing the 2nd fret note at the same time.

For the hammer-on, as John says, attack the string from directly above, with a quick movement. That doesn't mean as soon as the first note has been played, it means with a sudden finger movement. Different!

However, you ask for alternatives. Apart from playing each note, the other viable one, which won't sound the same, is to play the 4th fret, slide down to 2nd, then slide back up to 4th. The notes are the same, the effect different.